# How to automatically split video into clips

Tags: javascript, php, video-editing

I'm looking for a way to split movies into clips of a given time duration automatically. I have a lot of videos that I need to be able to break up and want them broken into something like 10 second clips. Is there a way to do this in something like javascript/php/etc something that can be ran on a server?

Basically if I upload a video I want it to split and be stored into separate videos.

Comment: did you find any solution to do this ?

Comment: @Alexy no, I didn't.